# Вопрос по Java и Github

Tags: java, intellij-idea, github

Я даже не знаю как правильно задать вопрос, сижу и перескакиваю с проблемы на проблему (точнее это не проблема, а мое незнание и отсутствие опыта). Я хочу создать проект на java, обычная консольная программка. И я хочу работать с ней через гитхаб, т.е. загрузить проект в гитхаб, делать коммиты и все такое. Я смотрел, как работать с гитхаб через *intelliJ IDEA*, потом наткнулся на инструкцию по решению моего застоя. Сделал по [этой инструкции](https://gist.github.com/inozemtsev32/85eb63ab96c0b7877d43aae0eff53320), но получилось так, что проект не запускается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*P.S. Как вы уже поняли на Java начал писать относительно недавно, раньше работал только с web* 
UPD: Еще не могли ли вы объяснить как работает структура решения Java, ну, в смысле зачем папка `/src` и почему там `com.company` *(имеется ввиду **не** этот проект, а вообще)*

Comment: Справился с ошибкой?

Comment: @Antonio112009 нет, все сделал по инструкции, вашей и еще одного ответа. Java11 в проекте присутствует

Comment: Да, прочти под моим ответом комментарии. Очень рекомендую

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделаем все по порядку:

1 - скачаем и установим JDK (допустим [Java SE Development Kit 11.0.2](https://jdk.java.net/11/))
2 - убедимся, что java11 установлен введя в командной строке/терминале/cmd строчку `java -version`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 - Заходим в Intellj.
4 - Заходим в `File - Project Structure`. Если у тебя написано "", то мы должны указать путь к нашему JDK файлу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5 - Если не указан JDK - нажимаем `New... -> JDK`. В теории, Intellij должно вас автоматически перебросить в папку с Java на вашем компе. Если у вас так же как на скрине ниже - то просто подтвердите, что выбрать нужно эту папку, если вы в другой папке - в Винде путь к вайлу будет в теории: `C:\Profram files\java\jdk11.0.2.jdk`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6 - Так же надо указать `Project Language level:` - `11 - Local variable syntax ...`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7 - Жмем в правом нижнем углу `OK`. Дальше Intellj должно "почуствовать" JDK в проекте и дать вам возможность запустить Java.

Добавление проекта на **Github**:

1 - Добавить проект на github от Intellij - [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf2-MOl0VXY)

Бонус:

Для Intellj есть удобный плагин: `.ignore` (Он поддерживает генерацию ignore-файлов для разных VCS)
Найти приложение можно в `File -> Settings -> Plugins`. В Верхней части панели выбираем `Marketplace`. В поисковике вводим `.ignore` и устанавливаем его.

[Ссылка на страницу плагина](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore)

Comment: при этом не забываем про подводные камни использования Oracle JDK 11 https://habr.com/ru/post/424579/

Comment: @ermak0ff Тогда какую же версию надо использовать?

Comment: Смысл такой - если JDK используется для личных нужд, тогда можно и Оракловсую юзать, если же это продакшн, тогда OpenJDK(если конечно не хотим платить денежку)

Comment: @ermak0ff для Open Source - тоже запрещено?

Comment: И для локального использования? ( сервер из 10 человек)

Comment: в статье есть выжимка из лицензионного соглашения - `Вы не можете использовать программы для любой обработки данных или для любых коммерческих, производственных или внутренних бизнес-целей, кроме разработки, тестирования, прототипирования и демонстрации вашего приложения;`
так что вы уже сами решайте подходит вам это для ваших целей или нет)

Answer (score 2):

1. Кнопки запуска недоступны, потому, что Вы не создали так называемый **run configuration**, его легко добавить нажав правой кнопкой мыши в редакторе, где открыт файл содержащий метод `public static void main()` и выбрать **run**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

2. `com.company.` это имя пакета, соглашение по именованию пакетов есть, но оно не так уж обязательно к исполнению, особенно для своих домашних проектов. Я для домашних проектов пишу `com.github.strangerintheq.` обычно это домен, принадлежащий Вам или Вашей организации, развернутый наоборот

Comment: По скрину видно, что проект не видит напрочь `main`-метод... Обычно java сразу его чуствует. Не ваш скрин)

Answer (score 2):

Идея создаёт проекты и модули, для этого надо использовать меню [File -> New project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html),

[image]

ну и далее предлагается выбрать из списка шаблон, который будет использоваться. Надо, чтобы это был java проект, тогда по шаблону создадится папка src и пометится как папка для сурсов. Тут долго объяснять как java работает и сразу хватать идею и начинать там безобразить не очень подходящее решение. Идея - это сложный инструмент и его  нужно использовать при вверенном знании java. Почему бы для начала не разобраться с jdk и не почитать [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). *Там* много примеров и знакомство с [netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org) наиболее простой способ понимания работы инструментов разработки.

У идеи также есть поддержка github, только она работает если у проекта есть интеграция с git. Что в общем то делается через VCS меню.